# consuming or consumable

Tags: adjectives

I was wondering which word is correct in the phrase below and why:

> time- and resource-consuming experimental methods
>
> time- and resource-consumable experimental methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to describe the experimental methods as consuming time and resources, so the first suggestion is the correct one. The time and resources are consumed.

We use the word "consumable" to refer to items that are used up (consumed), as opposed to items that can be used over and over again. Ink for a printer is consumable, but the printer itself generally isn't.